# Bind TreeNode with XmlNode in C# windows form

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, bind

So, this is the code, I whant the treeView1.Nodes to contain both TreeNodes and XmlNodes, particulary to store this class objects as in code above:

```
    public class Node : TreeNode
    {
        public XmlNode node{ set; get; }

        public Node(XmlNode node):base(){
            this.node = node;
            base.Text = node.Name;
        }

        public void delete()
        {
            node.RemoveAll();
            node = null;
            base.Remove();
        }
    }

   private void populate(XmlNodeList nodes, TreeNodeCollection tree)
    {
        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in nodes)
            {
                int index = tree.Add(new Node(child));
                if (child.ChildNodes != null)
                {
                    populate(child.ChildNodes, tree[index].Nodes );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now I realized that constructed **Node** objects are still being stored as **TreeNode**, how can I make the line above possible?

```
Node selected = treeView1.SelectedNode;
selected.delete();
```

Comment: If you know it will always be a `Node`, just cast it to that and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `Node` objects aren't being stored as TreeNodes, they **are** TreeNodes. Or rather, a subclass of `TreeNode`. So, in your case, if you know that all nodes in your tree will be of the type `Node`, you can simply cast to it:

```
Node selected = (Node)treeView1.SelectedNode;
```